# To check whether given equation is LDE and to find its solution

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

consider differential equation

|y'| + |y| = 0 
satisfying

0 < x <1 and y(0) = 1

im asked to CHECK WHETHER IT IS LINEAR DIFFERENTIAL EQUATION  AND whether it has unique solution . Problem is that of absolute signs which encloses y' . . im not sure what to do with this

Comment: $y=0$ is the only solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$|y'|+|y|=0, \forall x\in (0,1)$$ implies $|y'|=0$ and $y=0$ in $(0,1).$
Hence the solution would be $y(x)=0, \forall x\in (0,1)$ with $y(0)=1.$
Therefore the function $y$ have a discontinuity at $0$ and we can not say any thing about the solution in the region$(-\infty,0)\cup[1,\infty).$ Therefore this solution is not a unique one.

Comment: here o is not in our interval so why do we care about o ?

Comment: Thats becouse, it is given as an initial condition.

Comment: @Milan why do we need to say anything about other than interval 0<x<1 . ie  for -infinity to plus infinity